# How to use the CSS selector > in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI and trying to override some css from Grid item with withStyles which has this selector:

```
.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2 > .MuiGrid-item
```

If I target item wth withStyle it is overriden by the above selector because of its specificity.
I tried with 'spacing-xs-2 item':

```
const CustomGrid = withStyles({
  'spacing-xs-2 > item': {
    marginLeft: '22px',
    top: '-6px',
    backgroundColor: 'lightgrey',
    padding: '0px 10px 0px 0px',
    borderRadius: ' 5px',
  },
})(Grid);
```

but not working.
How can I use the selector > in material ui?

Comment: Why don't you just add className on that element and style it?

Comment: Because .MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2 > .MuiGrid-item will still override it

Comment: If you want to override some core elements in Material UI you have to use Theme there, here you have a link for that - https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work, but it's not how I would approach it

```js
const CustomGridItem = withStyles({
  item: {
    '.MuiGrid-spacing-xs-2 > &': {
      // your styles
    }
  }
})(Grid);
```

Instead, you can simply raise the specificity of your class style rules

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  item: {
    marginLeft: 22,
    top: -6,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderRadius: 5,
    "&&": { // => .makeStyles-item.makeStyles-item
      padding: "0px 10px 0px 0px"
    }
  }
});
```

```js
<Grid item className={classes.item}>
  // content
</Grid>
```